# Caracteres especiais em tela de menu batch script

Tags: batch

Sistema Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.1586

Tela mostra os códigos especiais como estão digitados.
Script:

```
color f0
@echo off
chcp 65001
cls
echo.
time /t
date /t

:menu
echo            ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo            º                          menu                           º                              
echo            º                                                         º
echo            ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹      
echo            º                                                         º
echo            º                Selecione a opção desejada:              º
echo            º                                                         º
echo            ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹
echo            º ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»     º
echo            º ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹     º
echo            º º1:Calculadora  ºº2:Redes        ºº 3: Conexao    º     º
echo            º ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼     º
echo            º ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»                                       º
echo            º ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹                                       º
echo            º º4:Sair         º                                       º
echo            º ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼                                       º
echo            º                                                         º
echo            º                                                         º
echo            º                                                         º
echo            º                                                         º
echo            º                                                         º
echo            ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼ 

set /p opcao=Digite a opcao.......
```

Resultado script:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ativar o reconhecimento de caracteres especiais para prompt de comando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova a parte de:

chcp 65001

ou substitua por:

chcp 850

Vai em Menu Arquivo, Salvar Como, em codificação escolha "ANSI".

Comment: Legal, a moldura da tela apareceu corretamente, só que a palavra opção, não reconheceu o til ~ e nem o cedilha ç. Se eu quiser usar este menu, vou ter que abrir mão da acentuação das palavras?

Comment: Tente usar "op‡Æo" ao in vez de "opção"

Comment: funcionou, mas existe um link que eu possa consultar para ver mais códigos, pois tenho outras palavras com acentuação que serão usadas neste menu, exemplo: conversão, será, área, áudios, etc...

Comment: Você abre um prompt de comando e digita por exemplo:

Comment: echo opção>teste.txt ai dentro de teste.txt aparece a palavra como ela deverá ser usada dentro do batch....

Comment: com algumas não deu, por exemplo máximos, não mostrou o código do á, no lugar dele ficou um caractere em branco.

Comment: Mias se você copiar colar "m ximos" no bat sai "máximos"...

Comment: ok, funciona. obrigado.